# Angular 12/rxjs: howto handle forkJoin in separate method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, fork-join

Have the following code snippet given, which does the following:

1. fetch the lists first
2. then once 1) is finished, call initRouter()

```js
ngOnInit(): void {

   forkJoin([
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC()
   ]).subscribe(res => {
        this.listA = res[0];
        this.listB = res[1];
        this.listC = res[2];
        this.initRouter();
   })
}
 
initRouter(){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params =>
      //do something with params and lists...
}
```

How can I put the first forkjoin-part into an own method like this:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {

   //Pseudo-Code:
   this.initListReturnForkJoin().subscribe(res => {
        this.listA = res[0];
        this.listB = res[1];
        this.listC = res[2];
        this.initRouter();
   })
}

//Pseudo-Code:
initListReturnForkJoin(): ??? {
   return forkJoin([
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC()
   ])
}
 
initRouter(){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params =>
      //do something with params and lists...
}
```

Sorry I don't know how to express this question better... any guidance is appreciated

Comment: yes, it would look exacly as you proposed. the return type would be `Observable<[listAtype, listBtype,listCtype]>`

Comment: Thanks for that!!

Answer (score 0):

Nested subscriptions are generally a code smell. You could use `forkJoin` again or try `withLatestFrom` (for example) to avoid nesting subscriptions.

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.route.params.pipe(
    // Update your lists every time the route emits
    withLatestFrom(this.fetchLists())
  ).subscribe(([params, listDict]) => {

    // Right here, both params and lists are defined
    this.doSomethingWithFetchedLists();

  });

}

// I don't know the types of your lists, 
// so I've put `any` as a placeholder for now.
fetchLists(): Observable<[any[],any[],any[]]> {

  return forkJoin({
    listA: this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA(),
    listB: this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB(),
    listC: this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC()
  }).pipe(
    tap(listDict => {
      // Update some global values as a side-effect of this
      // observable emitting. 
      this.listA = listDict.listA;
      this.listB = listDict.listB;
      this.listC = listDict.listC;
    })
  );
  
}
```